# unable to get longitude and latitude in android for real device

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

When I run the App on android emulator and pass the longitude and latitude values from DDMS i get the proper values and also the city name but when I install the .apk file into real device the values of longitude and latitude is set to 0.0 and 0.0. I turned on the gps and every other settings required but still unable to get the co-ordinates.

Manifest file:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"        />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: DO one thing..First switch on the gps,open the google maps apps,after that try opening your app..

Comment: ARe you getting any errors in logcat?? iF so please post your logcat..Post your manifest anyway..

Comment: That means GPS is not getting fixed..I think your GPS icon is blinking..right???So,Show your device to open sky and you can see that the gps icon becomes steady...

Comment: Add  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>` too in manifest..

Comment: Have you added onLocationChanged()???

Comment: OK try adding the permission and run once again..Mean while please  post you code too...

Comment: See this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/).. It explains in more detail..

Comment: Did you run the app after adding that permission??? Show your device to open sky while running your app..

Comment: Some times it doesnt work..I also got this issue some time earlier..Open the google maps activity and if it shows location then there is no problem..

Comment: I've added that as my answer..Kindly accept my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>` too in manifest..